# Hibernate cannot set values by Lombok setter

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lombok

I have entity class representing post as below.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Post {
  @Id
  private long id;
  private String title;
  private String content;
  private LocalDateTime created;
}
```

When I use jpaRepository to findAll posts I receive list of empty elements.

[Empty post response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heDub.jpg)

JpaRepository code :

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {}
```

PostService :

```
@Service
public class PostService {

@Autowired
private PostRepository postRepository;

   public List<Post> getPosts() {
   return postRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

Post Controller :

```
@RestController
public class PostController {

   private final PostService postService;

   PostController(PostService postService) {
       this.postService = postService;
   }

   @GetMapping("/posts")
   public List<Post> getPosts() {
       return postService.getPosts();
   }
}
```

I found that Hibernate propably cannot set values of Post that's why I got list of empty elements.
If I change post properties to public, everything works fine but I want to keep they private.
I guess @Setter annotation doesn't work and hibernate can't parse data into Post objects.

Can someone know how to fix it?

My gradle dependency section

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

}

Comment: Use @Data on entity level

Comment: Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below annotations instead:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
```